# NSLayoutConstraint Issue on different devices

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using NSLayoutconstraint but it seems to mess up the position of the views when passing from iphone 6 plus to iphone 6.

It should work since I'm creating constraint related to the attribute of the view that should change in case of using differente devices.

Here some example of constraint:

```
v=getBitmapView("V -.-")
    self.view.addSubview(v)
    var myConstraint =
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: v,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0)



    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)
     myConstraint =
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: v,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: -30)



    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)
    myConstraint =
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: v,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: -200)



    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)
    myConstraint =
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: v,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: -650)



    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)
```

If i ran iphone 6 plus the view is positioned 30 point above the bottom margin but if I use the iphone 6 the view disappears.

Comment: Don't hard code the height like that. For that last constraint, use `.Top` or `.TopMargin` (and obviously don't use `-650`, but whatever top margin that makes sense).

Comment: How can I set the width and height without hard coding? Do you have an example? Let's say i want to have a view 1/3 of the half of the screen that is 1/6 of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've hard-coded the height and width. Rather than using constants for width and height, define them as a multiple of some other view to the superview.

> How can I set the width and height without hard-coding? Do you have an example? Let's say i want to have a view 1/3 of the half of the screen that is 1/6 of the screen

Use the multiplier to accomplish this. If you just have the one subview, you can define the width and height as a multiple of the superview:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    blueView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor),                              // pin to top left corner
    blueView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor),

    blueView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / 3.0),   // one third the width
    blueView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / 2.0)  // one half the height
])
```

That yields:

[image]

Or, sometimes, you define a bunch of views to span the entire superview, and then define their widths relative to each other, e.g., the top half is one third blue and two thirds red, and the bottom half is all green:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    blueView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor),             // pin blue and red to the top
    redView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor),

    blueView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor),           // pin blue to left edge
    redView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(blueView.rightAnchor),       // pin red adjacent to blue view
    redView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor),          // pin red to right edge
    redView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(blueView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0), // but make red twice as wide as blue (i.e. 2/3rds entire view)

    greenView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(blueView.bottomAnchor),     // define green to be below blue
    greenView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(redView.bottomAnchor),      //   and red views

    greenView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(blueView.heightAnchor),  // but make it same height as blue

    greenView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor),      // and pin it to the bottom of superview

    greenView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor),          // and green spans entire superview
    greenView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor)
])
```

[image]

Clearly, if you'd rather instantiate a `NSLayoutConstraint` and then do `addConstraint`, like you have in your original example, then feel free. The above syntax (introduced in iOS 9) is just a more concise rendition, but the concept is the same as above, namely one should pin the edges as appropriate, but only define width/height as a multiple of another view, not using some hard-coded constant.